# Calculate average time between post and first comment in two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, time, average

I'm facing this (for me at least) challenge:

I have a forum where posts are stored in table `posts` and comments in table `comments`. When a post is made, the timestamp is stored in column INT(11) `posts.created_at`. Same with a comment... when a comment is made, with the comment a timestamp is stored in `comments.created_at`.

However, now I would like to know the average time in seconds it takes for a first comment to show up. Of course, when NO comment is given this should not be taken into the average.

Can this be done in one SQL query? If not, how could this be done with the least amount of queries?

Hope you have an idea, as I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will work for you:

```
select   avg(first_comments.first_time - posts.created_at)
from     posts
join    (select   comments.post_id
                  min(comments.created_at) as first_time
         from     comments
         group by post_id) as first_comments
on       first_comments.post_id = posts.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were using date type for the date fields then something like:

```
SELECT AVG(
           DATEDIFF(MIN(comments.created_at), posts.created_at)
          ) 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN comments on comments.post_primary_key = posts.primary_key
```

Should get you what you need

But as has been pointed out in comments, you aren't storing the dates as dates, with that in mind try:

```
SELECT AVG(
           MIN(comments.created_at) - posts.created_at
          ) 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN comments on comments.post_primary_key = posts.primary_key
```

For completeness - my latest suggestion...
You could try this:

```
SELECT AVG( sub.timeToComment ) 
FROM ( 
       SELECT MIN(comments.created_at) - posts.created_at as timeToComment 
       FROM posts 
       INNER JOIN comments on comments.post_primary_key = posts.primary_key
     ) as sub
```

But not sure it's that much different from @Xophmeister approach

Comment: Thanks! I'm about to test it! Indeed, I am storing numbers as timestamps. I guess that will be faster to calculate than DATEDIFF right?

Comment: Not sure to be honest - a date type probably gets stored as a long underneath all the wrappers anyway, and `datediff` probably makes use of that fact and so would be similar speeds, date columns just give you some handy functions without casting or converting all the time.

Comment: Isn't there a () too many ? NOt be be picky, but to understand.

Comment: Quite possibly - It's an overhang from the DATEDIFF. Will edit it ;)

Comment: While testing, it keeps giving me "1111 Invalid use of group function". What's wrong? Am I missing something I should know?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6008/discussion-between-glooh-and-matt-fellows)

Answer (score 1):

```
select   posts.id,
         avg(comments.created_at - posts.created_at)
from     posts
join     comments
on       comments.id = posts.id
group by posts.id;
```

This presumes that MySQL will correctly handle datetime arithmetic.

**EDIT** As @MattFellows points out, this query is incorrect as it groups by post; whether I take `min(comments.created_at)`, or not. Indeed, the result it will return is completely redundant: with the `min`, it will be the time between each post and its first comment; without the `min`, it's the average time between the post and all the comments (which is a rather spurious metric!)... I hang my head in shame :P

The correct query is:

```
select avg(min(comments.created_at) - posts.created_at)
from   posts
join   comments
on     comments.id = posts.id;
```

Although, again, this is where the timestamps are numeric, rather than datetime, which (apparently) MySQL doesn't have overloaded operators for.

Comment: There is a DATEDIFF function for date arithmetic and this will not provide an overall average. In fact it won't even restrict to the first comment as requested.

Comment: DATEDIFF is used to subtract two dates, but Glooh is saving time in INT(11) for some reason. Although your second point is valid. @MattFellows

Comment: @MattFellows I missed the `min` on the comment creation time: fixed. Didn't know about `datediff`.

Comment: This will still not get the overall average as you are grouping for each post.  This will get he average (Of only one result) for each post.

Comment: @MattFellows You're right: I misinterpreted the OP's question. The result of my query is somewhat pointless, as it currently stands... I guess I deserved that down-vote :P

Comment: @Xophmeister Thanks for your suggestion though! Much appreciated as well!

Comment: Feel free to fix it - there's a couple of hours before the downvote is un-removable. ;)

Comment: Should I use INNER JOIN or JOIN?? Because currently, it doesn't work (also Matt's option doesn't). Looks like issues with MIN

Comment: @Glooh `join` and `inner join` are synonymous. I would have a look at the timestamps, to see if they are what you expecting.

Comment: I get "1111 Invalid use of group function" on the query and nothing helps.

Comment: Note that, in my code above, the `comments.id = posts.id` might be misleading: the `comments.id` field is the post's foreign key. My point being that you should check you are using the right key: i.e., `comments.post_id = posts.post_id`. If that is still causing problems, try adding a `having` clause to the end of the query: `having count(comments.created_at)>=1`

Comment: @Xophmeister If I removed AVG(), only one record is returned. If I remove MIN() all lines are returned so I think that MIN() only takes the absolute minimum or something.

Maybe a sub query should be used? HAVING option didn't do anythin.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6004/discussion-between-glooh-and-xophmeister)

Comment: @Glooh: I don't have time to chat, right now, so I've just posted an alternative solution using an inline view, as you suggest.